# require_once works in PHP 5.6 but not in PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have the following line in my code, which works fine in PHP-5.6, but not in PHP-7.1.

```
require_once '/app/plugin.php';
```

When I change it to one of the following, the it works with PHP-7.1?

```
require_once './app/plugin.php';
```

or

```
require_once 'app/plugin.php';
```

What is wrong here with the first line of the code?

Comment: Filepaths: `/app/plugin.php` is from filesystem root; `./app/plugin.php` or `app/plugin.php` are relative to the current working directory... why it worked fine in PHP5.6 is probably very bad security for your system

Comment: @MarkBaker how can I fix this security issue in PHP-5.6?

Comment: The sucurity problem is that you have script files in the server's `/app` folder, when they almost certainly shouldn't be there... move them to the appropriate location

Comment: This question needs some debugging details?

Comment: @MarkBaker  I'm not sure I get it, to me it seems that php 5.6 security is better, since if you use absolute path it ALWAYS take docroot's path as root thus it's caged. so in php 5.6 `/` means `wwwroot` not filesystem root. How is PHP 7 behaviour better?

Comment: @MirrorMirror I'm not sure that's accurate. PHP 5.6 can still attempt to open files when accessed from the root e.g. like `/etc/something` what is happening here is probably that there are some extra paths defined as include paths in the php.ini of php 5.6 which are not also present in php 7 or possibly PHP 5.6 accesses files relative to the doc root in addition (not instead of) the filesystem root

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong here with the first line of the code?

Well first of all lets take note that it's fine for PHP 5.6 (in your setup) while not for 7.x. So it can't be *entirely* wrong, just saying.

And even your report astonishes me - never experienced it before - this may already explain a bit and lead to a solution.

Even in PHP 5.6 it is perfectly safe to use the so called *Magic Constant* `__DIR__`  that refers to the directory of the PHP script itself.

This is handy, esp. for *relative* include / require paths.

Let's make it an example:

```php
require_once '/app/plugin.php';
```

is your current (PHP 5.6) code. Let's make use of `__DIR__`:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/app/plugin.php';
```

If you can confirm it working on PHP 5.6 my understanding is, that this modified code should be portable to PHP 7 and later (the next versions after PHP 5.6) as `__DIR__` always contains the absolute (, real) path to the *to-require* script so you can use it to *safely* express relations to other files.

---

> As a note in the margin: `require_once` also relates to *realpath* (like `__DIR__`) so this is compatible (with only some overhead in file-system *stat* calls, but I'm sure they can be ignored in context of this answer).

---

Again:

> What is wrong here with the first line of the code?

At least in PHP 7 and above it seems that the resolution is correct to the *current working directory* and that means that PHP 7+ looks for a file at the absolute path:

```
/app/plugin.php
```

That file *most likely* does not exist on that box. `/` is the root of the file-system and *any* path that start with a slash (`/`) is an absolute path.

*Perhaps* (as written I personally never experienced this) PHP 5.6 *might* be the culprit not adhering to this POSIX/UNIX/LINUX convention about what constitutes and absolute or relative path (the leading slash).

---

My personal suggestion: Go with the standard, leading slash = absolute path. Use `__DIR__` for your benefit in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different include paths set in PHP5 and PHP7. Run `get_include_path()` and compare result for both PHP versions.

Comment: I checked it, the results for both the versions are same.